# using awk or send to find a string and insert another complex string , before it

Tags: string, search, insert, sed, awk

Ok I am locked in a situation where I am trying to insert a line based on a search string . I am familiar doing this w AWK and SED using a single work or something uncomplicated.

How I'd like to insert a string that has Single  Quotes and Brackets 
e.g. 
this will work

```
     awk '/('Backup/ {print "NEWLINE"  } {print}' filename.sh
```

and so will this

```
    sed -e '/\(\'backup/i\
    newline ' filename.sh
```

Instead of newline work- I want this  " ('Drop the  no good white.cap ;' ) , "

everything enclosed within the " and "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do has nothing to do with `awk` or `sed`. For example, see:

```
print " '\'' data_between_two_single_quotes '\'' "
```

The first `'` character closes the opening `'` shell string literal. The shell literal does not support a backslash escape for this. The sequence `'\''` does the trick: it closes the single-quote literal, specifies the quote character (using an escape that is supported outside of single-quote literals) and then re-opens a new single-quote literal. You can think of it as a four-character escape sequence to get a single quote.

So, your `awk` command becomes:

```
awk '/\('\''Backup/ {print " ('\''Drop the no good white.cap ;'\'' ) , " } { print }' filename.sh
```

And your `sed` command becomes:

```
sed -e '/\('\''Backup/i\
('\''Drop the no good white.cap ;'\'' ) , ' filename.sh
```

---

***EDIT:***

```
for i in *; do awk -v database="$DB" -v table="$TB" 'BEGIN { print "header" } /backup/ { print " ('\''DROP TABLE " database "." table ";'\'' ) , " }1' "$i" > "${i}.new"; done
```

Explanation:

Loop over all files in the directory using a shell `for` loop. Add a header to the files with the `BEGIN` block. Find the word `backup` and print a line containing the shell variables `DB` and `TB`. `... }1'` at the end of the `awk` script enables printing by default. It's shorthand for `{ print }`. HTH.

Comment: awk '/BACKUP/{print " ('\''Drop the no good white.cap ;'\'' ) , " } { print }' filename.sh does seem to work but lets say I have variables inside ...                                                               awk '/BACKUP/{print " ('\''DROP TABLE $DB.$TB ;'\'' ) , " } { print }' filename.sh  How can we expand them. THANKS SO MUCH for your help

Comment: sorry that was a dup of the above post- Saul

Comment: it gives syntax error awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: I think you use awk -v database=$DB -v table=$TB '$0 ~ database , $0 ~ table' filename  BUT I dont know how to couple the logic with the rest of the stuff that follows

Comment: Hi Steve I dont see the edit . Can you pl repost.. thanks galore

Comment: If I run this .. I still land w/ the same error                                                                            awk -v database=$DB -v table=$TB '/backup/{print " ('\''DROP TABLE databasetable ;'\'' ) , " } { print }' filename

Comment: even if I remove the quotes `awk -v database=$DB.....` it still gives the same error even this one `awk -v database="$DB" -v table="$TB" '/BACKUP/ {print " ('\''DROP TABLE " database "." table ";'\'' ) , " } { print }' filename.sh`
 gives the same error. It maybe because those would refer to string assignments as against variables and this `awk -v database=$DB -v table=$TB '$0 ~ database , $0 ~ table' filename` might work but i am not sure how to extend that with the rest of my logi

Comment: what I am trying to do is edit a whole bunch of files in a dir via lopping the file name is the variable. Inside the loop 2 things will be done . Add a header line  ( done already ) and 2nd : look for a specific word and add a line before it  BUT the line has variable tablename and db name .

Comment: This one also gets the same error `awk -v database="$DB" -v table="$TB" '$0 ~ database || $0 ~ table || /backup/ { print " ('\''DROP TABLE " database "." table ";'\'' ) , " }1' file
` thank you . Will await

Comment: @user1874594: Please see the update. It will do exactly as you ask (well, rather as I understand it). Also, would you mind deleting some of the above comments? This will make it easier for others to read. Simply mouse-over the comment and click the cross. Let me know if you have any problems. Please keep the comment 'what I am trying to do is...'

Comment: @user1874594: So how'd you go?

Comment: @user1874594 The error message `syntax error near line 1 awk: bailing out near line 1` means you're using old, broken awk. If you're on solaris use one of these in order of preference: gawk, /usr/xpg4/bin/awk, nawk. Now, stop all this crazy quoting and jumping back and forth between awk and shell, do it as @steve told you.

Comment: THANKS GALORE STEVE. TGI Fridays for you and Ed. I tweaked it just a tad and it worked  just fine `nawk -v database="$DB" -v table="$TB" 'BEGIN { print "do diddle do header" } /BACKUP/ { print " ('\''DROP TABLE " database "."
table ";'\'' ) , " }1' $file
`

Answer (score 1):

Another way using awk:

Keep your content to be inserted in a separate file:

```
$ cat file1
 " ('Drop the no good white.cap ;' ) , "
```

Using awk:

```
$ awk '/\('\''Backup/{getline x<"file1";print x;}1'  filename.sh
```

Using getline, the line in the file1 is read into the variable x, and printed on encoutering a pattern. This will allow you not to you any escape characters to escape the quotes.

Comment: even this one `awk -v database="$DB" -v table="$TB" '/BACKUP/ {print " ('\''DROP TABLE " database "." table ";'\'' ) , " } { print }' filename.sh
` gives the same error